# Mongodb global connection redundancy

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am new to web development and I am working on new project using mongodb, nodejs.

I am trying to set up a global connection for the whole project, but when I pass the object app to initialize database I face a problem of more than 5 connections opened in the same time.

Here is my set up for the mongo connection:

```
var options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
        console.log('waiting database...');
        let MONGO_LINK = `mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_MDP}@localhost
                                   :${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`;
        MongoClient.connect(MONGO_LINK, options, async function (err, client) {
            if (err) console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB: ' + err);
            console.log('We have connected to mongodb');
            app.db = client.db("residanat");
            initDatabase(app);
            app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, 
                () => { console.info(`REST API running on port ${port}`); });
            process.on('SIGINT', () => {
                console.log('SIGINT: Closing MongoDB connection');
                client.close();
                process.exit(0);
            });
        });
```

> initDatabase (app call the file initDatabase.js which calls the other model to define mongodb schema)

here is initDatabase.js

```
const utilisateurModal = require('../modals/Utilisateur.modal'),
    produitModal = require('../modals/Produit.modal'),
    objectifModal = require('../modals/Objectif.modal'),
    questionModal = require('../modals/Question.modal'),
    produitClient=require('../modals/ProduitClient.model'),
    questionClient=require('../modals/QuestionClient.model'),
    notificationModal = require('../modals/Notification.modal'),
    paiementModal=require('../modals/Paiement.modal'),
    revenueModal=require('../modals/Revenue.modal'),
    produitAnalyseModal=require('../modals/ProduitAnalyse.modal');

module.exports = function initDatabase(app) {
    utilisateurModal(app);
    produitModal(app);
    objectifModal(app);
    questionModal(app);
    produitClient(app);
    questionClient(app);
    notificationModal(app);
    paiementModal(app);
    revenueModal(app);
    produitAnalyseModal(app);

}
```

and here an example of models

```
module.exports = function UtilisateurModal(app) {
    app.db.createCollection("utilisateur", {
        validator: {
            $jsonSchema: {
                bsonType: "object",
                additionalProperties: false,
                required: ["name", "email", "pswd", "role", "dateInsert"],
                properties: {
                    name: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        description: "must be a string and is required"
                    },
                    email: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        pattern: "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/",
                        description: "must be an email format and is required",
                    },
                    pswd: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        description: "password is required"
                    },
                    dateNaissance: {
                        bsonType: "date",
                        description: "must be a valid birth date"
                    },
                    role: _role,
                    image: {
                        bsonType: "string"
                    },
                    telephone: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                    },
                    pays: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        description: ""
                    },
                    ville: {
                        bsonType: "string"
                    },
                    adresse: {
                        bsonType: "string"
                    },
                    posteCode: {
                        bsonType: "string"
                    },
                    isdeleted: {
                        bsonType: "bool",
                        default: false
                    },
                    dateInsertion: { bsonType: "timestamp" },
                    dateModif: { bsonType: "timestamp" },
                }
            }
        },
    });
    app.db.collection("utilisateur").createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
    app.db.collection("utilisateur").createIndex({ role: 1 }, { sparse: true });
    app.db.collection("utilisateur").createIndex({ isdeleted: 1 });
}

let _role = {
    bsonType: "string",
    enum: ["superadmin", "client", "editor"],
    description: "role can only be one of announced choices"

};
```

the problem is when I launch the app I found in mongodb log file that there are many open connections

logFile:

```
2019-12-06T23:26:15.302+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64697 #17 (1 connection now open)
2019-12-06T23:26:15.309+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn17] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64697 conn17: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.3.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "18.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.17.0, LE (unified)" }
2019-12-06T23:26:15.331+0100 I  ACCESS   [conn17] Successfully authenticated as principal nodejsApi on residanat from client 127.0.0.1:64697
2019-12-06T23:26:15.372+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64699 #18 (2 connections now open)
2019-12-06T23:26:15.372+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn18] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64699 conn18: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.3.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "18.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.17.0, LE (unified)" }
2019-12-06T23:26:15.381+0100 I  ACCESS   [conn18] Successfully authenticated as principal nodejsApi on residanat from client 127.0.0.1:64699
2019-12-06T23:26:15.384+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64701 #19 (3 connections now open)
2019-12-06T23:26:15.385+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn19] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64701 conn19: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.3.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "18.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.17.0, LE (unified)" }
2019-12-06T23:26:15.392+0100 I  ACCESS   [conn19] Successfully authenticated as principal nodejsApi on residanat from client 127.0.0.1:64701
2019-12-06T23:26:15.395+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64703 #20 (4 connections now open)
2019-12-06T23:26:15.395+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn20] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64703 conn20: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.3.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "18.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.17.0, LE (unified)" }
2019-12-06T23:26:15.400+0100 I  ACCESS   [conn20] Successfully authenticated as principal nodejsApi on residanat from client 127.0.0.1:64703
2019-12-06T23:26:15.402+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64705 #21 (5 connections now open)
2019-12-06T23:26:15.403+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn21] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64705 conn21: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.3.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "18.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.17.0, LE (unified)" }
2019-12-06T23:26:15.407+0100 I  ACCESS   [conn21] Successfully authenticated as principal nodejsApi on residanat from client 127.0.0.1:64705
```

So it's not a code problem it's an understanding of concept so can anybody help me by explain how to found a solution, thank you